# Where can I find dungeons in WoW?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Three of us newbies decided to play WoW, and we want to do a dungeon instead of a random question. We are level 7-8, so there is no dungeon finder for us. Furthermore, we are playing the trial edition. We chose the Night Elf race. Where can we find a dungeon that allows us to slay a boss and do some teamwork?

Note: We are around the area where you first fly. I forget the city name.

Comment: You are too low a level for any instances. As soon as you all hit level 15, you'll be able to queue for Deadmines and Ragefire Chasm, the easiest dungeons.

Answer (score 9):

Check [this list of instances by level](http://www.wowwiki.com/Instances_by_level) if you need to know information about instances in the future.

The lowest level instance for the Alliance race is [Deadmines](http://www.wowwiki.com/The_Deadmines), often called DM or VC (Boss: VanCleef).
The suggested level for this instance is 15 - 21, the minimal level is 10.

So, it's best to level a bit further, the dungeon will then be available in the dungeon finder and allow you to teleport there instead of going through a lot of transport. At a lower level, it's unlikely that you will be able to reach the entrance. Even at the minimal level, it's unlikely that you will be able to reach the boss properly. Unless you take a very high level with you...

Comment: Dungeons have suggested levels for groups of 5. If you want to go in with just 3, you'll want to be a higher level than the suggested levels, but then the gear and experience you get won't be as good. You'll get the best experience playing with a full group.

Comment: If they use the dungeon finder they will automatically match up with 2 other players.

Comment: Do you have to "find" the dungeon before you can queue on the dungeon finder? I know that this was a requirement for 80-85 instances.

Answer (score 2):

iirc, the first dungeons are available in the 18-26 level range.

Here's a link to [Wowwiki's instance guide](http://www.wowwiki.com/Instances_by_level)...Should tell you where, and what level you ought to be.

Note: if you're at or around the recommended level, you're going to need a full group of five, with the usual dedicated healer/dedicated tank. If you want to run it with only 3, you'll need to be better geared and higher level.

I'd recommend hooking up with a leveling guild. They're usually noob friendly, and there are often people willing to run you through lower level instances.